# How to get lowest integer from objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically what I'm trying to achieve, is the lowest integer from an object thats in an array with other objects.

```
r.Collection
```

is an array that holds 3 objects, so it looks something like this:

```
[{foo:"bar",abc:"xyz",number:1},{foo:"car",abc:"hcu",number:2},{foo:"tar",abc:"uif",number:3}]
```

Now the goal, is to sort through this array.  and look at each of the number values, once it finds the lowest value. I need it to pull that entire object out of the array to use later.

Currently what i'm trying to do isn't working and i'm not sure. I could be doing this totally wrong

```
 for (o in r.Collection) {
                    var data = r.Collection[o]
                    console.log(Math.min(data.number))
                }
```

I know to use Math.min to find the smallest number in an array, but when I run this code, every object gets printed.

How do I sort through this array, to pull our the object with the lowest number value?

Answer (score 4):

`Math.min` is a little to simple for this — there's no way to specify what you mean by min in an object with several values.

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop over the items in the list and keep track of the current lowest. The result will be the lowest in the list based on the function passed to reduce:

```js
let l = [{foo:"bar",abc:"xyz",number:1},{foo:"car",abc:"hcu",number:2},{foo:"tar",abc:"uif",number:3}]

let lowest = l.reduce((lowest, item) => item.number < lowest.number ? item: lowest)
console.log(lowest)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.min()` can work, but it would require that you use destructuring and some massaging of the array index to account for 0-base.

```js
var r = {};
r.collection = [{foo:"bar",abc:"xyz",number:1},{foo:"car",abc:"hcu",number:2},{foo:"tar",abc:"uif",number:3}];
var min = r.collection[Math.min(...(r.collection.map(function(item){return item.number})))-1];

console.log(min);
```

Comment: Does this require the array to already be sorted? Unless I'm misunderstanding something this seems to fail when array is not already sorted by `number`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes, it does. This is why I say it can work, but it's not the best approach.

Comment: Actually it seems to require that `number` corresponds to the index in the array. For example, given `[{foo:"bar",abc:"xyz",number:2},{foo:"car",abc:"hcu",number:5}]` it returns the item number 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply sort the array via [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and pick the first item from it:

```js
let data = [{foo:"car",abc:"hcu",number:2},{foo:"bar",abc:"xyz",number:1},{foo:"tar",abc:"uif",number:3}]

let result = data.sort((a,b) => a.number - b.number)[0]

console.log(result)
```

If you need the `max` simply reverse the sort by `b.number - a.number` etc.